# Filemanager component for ember cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

I need to implement file management functionality and tried to find some addon to reuse it but unfortuanlelly have found nothing for ember.

Is there some addon for ember like angular-filemanager or any file management addon?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

An ember file manager addon does not exist yet.
For now, you could create an ember-cli addon wrapper for the [elFinder FileManager](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder)